# Web based IDE solution

Tags: php, javascript, ide, cloud

What I want to do is, to work on my projects from "everywhere" with internet connection

I tried followings:

- Tried to connect from my office to main PC with remote desktop apps like: Team Viewer, etc.. It's very slow and boring. (Seeing what I typed after 2-3 second delay, and it's really annoying)
- Carrying laptop with myself also not good idea. (It's weight about 4-5 kg.)
- Flash drive also not good idea... All my projects together is about 20-30 GB.

The only comfortable way for me is: **web based IDE** (something like Netbeans, I mean in-built project management,etc.. BUT web based).

I was looking for Web based IDE which supports PHP, HTML, JS and other various languages. My main PC is always connected to internet. So if there is any good open source (or free) solution, I can serve this IDE either from my webhosting account or directly from my PC. (For ex. this service http://c9.io/ is exactly what I need. But there are some problems: 1 its paid. 2 I don't want to host my projects in third party servers. I need something like that, but want to instal such system on my own servers )

What do you think about this/what's your suggestion? Thx in advance...

Comment: Forget web-based IDEs. Use an SSH connection to a server that runs Vim or Emacs configured with all the necessary project management & debugging plugins.  You can even leave your session running in a `screen` session.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Online PHP IDE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33897/online-php-ide)

Comment: @Michael it will be something with GUI or console?

Comment: @epic_syntax Console, but don't think of it like a console. Properly configured, they have full mouse support multiple split windows, more powerful scripting & syntax highlighting than any IDEs, _extreme_ portability across machines and platforms, I could go on....

Answer (score 4):

You should check out Codiad - http://www.codiad.com - you can host it on your own server, configure it to do what you need, and access it anywhere.

Comment: Codiad is really recommended - very fast, plenty of features for developer productivity, easy to customize

Answer (score 1):

If you want to work on a project from anywhere, then you may want to look at using a decentralised version control system like Git instead. Advantages is you can work on any machine with Git and an IDE or text editor, and not relying on a third-party, web-based service that can do anything with your data or may disappear overnight.

Comment: Is there any tutorial or something like that to setup server like you said?

Comment: Yes. Lots. Google. A good one: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/get-started-with-git/

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative way of solving the problem: All my projects are hosted on GitHub. I split my work between three computers. When I sit down to work on a project I run `git pull` and any changes I’ve made on the others get pulled down. You won’t have to re-sync all 20GB of data, just the bits that you’ve changed. Then you can continue to work using native OS applications.

You can install Git, for free, on your own server.

Comment: Is there any tutorial or something like that to setup server like you said?

Comment: Not that I know of, if I get a moment I’ll find one or write one up and post it here.

Answer (score 1):

**So** you want a **free** web-based IDE that allows you to set the project folder in your own server? That's doable I guess, but I am not sure whether anyone has done it yet.

There's always **vim** though. I use it a lot and, while there's somewhat of a learning curve to it, you can use it anywhere there's a console (linux or putty on windows) and I think it has all of the features you've mentioned.

Comment: can you help me to setup this on my computer? via teamviewer

Comment: this only works if your code is on a linux server.You just need to **ssh** into your server and start using it, really. If **vim** is not present then you can download it or use **vi** instead. That's the most efficient way of remotely editing files I know of.